# Django multi project user management

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, project-management

I want to learn is there a way to keep django multi project and authenticate/authorize them with one project?

For example:

I have Project-B and Project-C with different operation fields like hotel automation and gas station. Both of them are my products and I want to manage them by keep licences and users in one place, in other words different project, Project-A.

In Project-B and Project-C has it's own apps and apps' models so I don't want to merge them in one project, I want to keep them separate. But I want authorize/authenticate users from one place Project-A. So Project-A will be used only for management.

I am planning to use OAuth toolkit for it, but in the first place I have another problem. Project-B and Project-C's apps' models have foreign key fields and many to many fields that defined in Project-A like customer itself.

Authentication can be solved Rest Framework and OAuth2 I think but I don't have a solution for this problem.

Can you help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any thoughts or solution?

Comment: I think, instead of holding all User specific Data inside Project A, make Project A just an API Client, which has access on modifying the user data within project B and C.
(Maybe unless you are going to have Users who will be using both project at the same time)

Comment: If you are going to create more Projects, you could add them somewhat easily to your "License Management System" (Project A) after implementing the API endpoints the first time

Comment: Thanks for answering. So users for Project-B will kept in Project-B and so on for other projects, this is your suggestion did I get it right? I think it could work but I am not sure it's a best practice or not. Besides how can I act for the possibility that you mentioned getting same users for group of projects, do you have further suggestion about it?

Comment: Yes, you've got it right. Well in my opinion, either method has pro and cons, pro being cleanly seperating users from each others by projects, easy implementation for the api, con is duplicate code for the api endpoints and maybe duplicate users between projects. Otherwise, if you want to keep all users within project A you have to provide some kind of authentication workflow for every view the user is visiting.

Comment: For your second question,
You need an identifier between projects which is always unique, like for example the users email address, within your Project A you could match duplicates across projects like that

Comment: Thx for elaborated answers. So with less code usage and effective way to make it happen this kinda project I need to make Project-A an API Client I think. But I am still struggling to decide Project-A's role in this scenario. Could you give an example that Project-A modification  that effectively affect to the Project-B and Project-C?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243070/discussion-between-nbsas-and-sativa).